# 'Chasing sides' in a geometry problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Consider the circle $W=x^2+y^2=81$. Let $AB$ be a diameter of circle $W$. $AB$ is extended through $A$ to $C$. Point $T$ lies on $W$ so that line $CT$ is tangent to $W$. Point $P$ is the foot of the perpendicular from $A$ to the line $CT$. Find the maximum value of $BP$.

I am unable to get expressions for the sides. Some hints are highly appreciated. I am thinking of power of a point, secant tangent theorem should do. But finding $BP$ is a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may suppose that $A(9,0),B(-9,0),C(c,0)$ where $c\gt 9$. Let $O(0,0)$.

Since we have $OT=9,OC=c$, we have $\sin\angle{TCO}=\frac 9c,\cos\angle{TCO}=\sqrt{1-(9/c)^2}$. Hence, the equation of the line $CT$ :
$$y-0=\tan(\pi-\angle{TCO})(x-c)$$
can be written as
$$y=\frac{-9}{\sqrt{c^2-81}}(x-c)\tag1$$
Hence, the equation of the line $AP$ can be written as
$$y-0=\frac{\sqrt{c^2-81}}{9}(x-9)\tag2$$
Now the point $P$ is the intersection point of $(1)$ with $(2)$, so we can have
$$P\left(\frac{9c^2+81c-729}{c^2},\frac{9c-81}{c^2}\sqrt{c^2-81}\right)$$

Hence, we have
$$\begin{align}BP^2=\left(\frac{9c^2+81c-729}{c^2}-(-9)\right)^2+\left(\frac{9c-81}{c^2}\sqrt{c^2-81}-0\right)^2=\frac{81(5c^2+18c-243)}{c^2}\end{align}$$
From here, you should be able to get the maximum value of $BP$.